# Troubleshooting IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to figure out why my web page isn't displaying when using my domain name. I have a local IIS 7 web server installed with an ASP.NET web site. When I go to `http://localhost`, my page displays fine. When I go to `http://www.mysite.com`, it doesn't display though. Doing a trace route on www.mysite.com shows that it is resolving to my IP address. My router is forwarding port 80 requests to the web server and I am browsing from my phone, which is on a separate IP address using 3G. I disabled my firewall and my anti-virus to make sure neither of those are interfering. I also looked at the IIS 7 log and my request does not appear to be hitting it.

Is there a way to trace the incoming request to find out where its getting thrown out at? I'm losing my mind trying to troubleshoot this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your ISP blocking port 80? I have seen lots of ISP's do this to home users in an attempt to have them upgrade their internet package to a business plan.

Comment: No, I don't think so. The weird part is, this was working last night. Now its not for some reason